# How to get input type of edittext in Espresso Testing?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I have a toggle `button` in my password `editText` which makes it's input type either text or password depending on what is checked. I am able to perform the typing and clicking the toggle button but I am not sure which should be the ViewAssertion in the espresso matcher function.

My code looks like below.

```
@Test
    public void checkToggleButton(){
        String password="anuran123";

        onView(withId(R.id.passET)).perform(typeText(password), closeSoftKeyboard());

        onView(withId(R.id.visibilityToggle)).perform(click());

        onView(withId(R.id.passET)).check(matches(allOf(/*NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE AS isDiplayed() won't work here.*/)))
    }
```

Comment: have look [Espresso testing for edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33700987/5110595)

Comment: that did not help. I am able to write in editText. what I wanted is changing the input type of it.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way of showing/hiding a password is by setting a [TransformationMethod](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/TransformationMethod.html), so in your test you might want to have a Matcher checking that:

```
private Matcher<View> isPasswordHidden() {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, EditText>(EditText.class) {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("Password is hidden");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(EditText editText) {
            //returns true if password is hidden
            return editText.getTransformationMethod() instanceof PasswordTransformationMethod;
        }
    };
}
```

and use it like this:

```
@Test
public void testIsPasswordHidden() throws InterruptedException {
    onView(withId(R.id.password)).perform(typeText("password"));
    onView(withId(R.id.password)).check(matches(isPasswordHidden()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With little experimenting I found that there is a ViewMactcher named withInputType that does the thing. So final code will be like below

```
@Test
    public void checkToggleButton(){
        String password="anuran123";

        onView(withId(R.id.passET)).perform(typeText(password), closeSoftKeyboard());

        onView(withId(R.id.visibilityToggle)).perform(click());

        onView(withId(R.id.passET)).check(matches(allOf(withInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT))));
    }
```

Comment: this solution does not give you a clue about the edit text input type. I mean you don't know if the password is revealed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just asses that getInputType() equals your desired type.

```
 /**
     * Get the type of the editable content.
     *
     * @see #setInputType(int)
     * @see android.text.InputType
     */
    public int getInputType() {
        return mEditor == null ? EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL : mEditor.mInputType;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The below matches a password field:

```
        onView(withId(R.id.passET))
                .check(
                        matches(
                                withInputType(
                                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
                                        | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                                )
                        )
                );
```

For a normal text field, you can use:

```
        onView(withId(R.id.passET))
                .check(
                        matches(
                                withInputType(
                                        InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                                )
                        )
                );
```

A simple way to get all the applied types is to use the Evaluate Expression feature in Android Studio's debugger to get: passET.getInputType(). Then use a combination of the appropriate constants in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType